# How to display the value of a variable as text using pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.7 with pygame 1.9.4.

My application requires that the value of a variable is displayed onto a pygame screen.

Currently, I have:

```
tnr = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 30)
text2 = tnr.render(timePriorities, False, (0, 0, 0))
screen.blit(text2,(0,0))
```

This outputs this error:

```
TypeError: text must be a unicode or byte
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thx!

Oh, and this is the related code:

```
timePriorities = 1.1
timeRightTurn = 2.2
timeDeadEnd = 3.3
timeIntersection = 4.4
array = sorted([timePriorities,timeRightTurn,timeDeadEnd,timeIntersection])
arrayLength = len(array)
tnr = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 30)
for i in range(0,arrayLength):
    if timePriorities == array[i]:
        str(timePriorities)
        text1 = tnr.render('Priorities', False, (0, 0, 0))
        text2 = tnr.render(timePriorities, False, (0, 0, 0))
    else:
        if timeRightTurn == array[i]:
            str(timeRightTurn)
            text3 = tnr.render('Right Turn', False, (0, 0, 0))
            text4 = tnr.render(timeRightTurn, False, (0, 0, 0))
        else:
            if timeDeadEnd == array[i]:
                str(timeDeadEnd)
                text5 = tnr.render('Dead End', False, (0, 0, 0))
                text6 = tnr.render(timeDeadEnd, False, (0, 0, 0))
            else:
                if timeIntersection == array[i]:
                    str(timeIntersection)
                    text7 = tnr.render('Intersection', False, (0, 0, 0))
                    text8 = tnr.render(timeIntersection, False, (0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that str(timePriorities) does not change timePriorities to a string, it returns the value as a string.

You need to assign it like so:

```
timePriorities = str(timePriorities)
```

Or, you can do it in render like this:

```
text2 = tnr.render(str(timePriorities), False, (0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: I've tried inputting it as a float, no success. I've tried converting it to a string, no success.

Comment: Can you post all the code so I can take a look? And what line are you getting the error.

Comment: Umm... Good luck reading ~2000 lines... But I'll post the lines that matter in.

Comment: The issue is that str(timePriorities) does not change timePriorities to a string, it returns the value as a string. You need to assign it like so: timePriorities = str(timePriorities) OR you can do it in render like this: text2 = tnr.render(str(timePriorities), False, (0, 0, 0))

Comment: @user2379875 you should add that to the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer.